# What does it mean to say a differential equation is an eigenvalue problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

My text says the following

$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x^2 \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right) + \lambda y = 0,\;\;\;0\le x\le 1,\; y(1)=c\ge0$$

is an "eigenvalue problem".

I don't understand the significance of calling it an eigenvalue problem. This equation can be solved by expanding the leftmost expression and recognising that it has the form of Euler's equation. I'm really struggling to see what's "eigenvalue" about it compared to other second order homogeneous linear differential equations I've seen in the past.

This is in the context of Sturm-Louiville systems with the more general equation
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(p(x) \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right) + (q(x)+\lambda w(x) )\,y = 0
$$

Comment: I think this problem may be incompletely specified as stated.  The equation is second order, but you only give one boundary condition $y(1) = c$.  Any comments?

Comment: Probably the text call it that way because it can be put in the form of an eigenvalue equation $Ay=\lambda y$, with $A=-\frac{d}{dx}x^2\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: @RobertLewis yes, thanks, this is an exercise -- part (a) is to find the general solution and show it has no eigenvalues for $c=0$ and infinite eigenvalues for $c>0$. I can follow the solution, I'm just confused over the use of the "eigenvalue problem" terminology.

Comment: @enzotib thanks, good point. It's a bit less obvious what $A$ is for the more general equation. Also I'm struggling to understand why "eigenvalue" is being used here and not in other places where second order homogeneous linear differential equations have appeared. Perhaps it's because Sturm-Louiville systems are the result of modelling physical systems where eigenvalues are physically significant?

Comment: I'm going to have to mull this one over for awhile . . .